# JavaScript: function myFunction(**What's This**);

Tags: javascript, html, function

when using javascript, if you put something in the parenthesis of a function, like:

```
<button onclick="myFunction('Hello')">Click Here!</button>
```

and in the JS:

```
function myFunction(i);
```

Does it define `var i = "Hello"` as soon as it is run, or something else?

Comment: Yes, it passes the variable. It's called an argument. [But is it a five minute argument or the full half hour?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQFKtI6gn9Y)

Comment: This is a tutorial-level question. Read one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it define var i = "Hello" as soon as it is run, or something else?

When the call occurs, the *value* `"Hello"` is passed into the function, which receives it using the *argument* called `i`. So within the function code, referring to `i` gives you the value `"Hello"`.

In your example, the call occurs when the user clicks on the button, because that click triggers the code in the `onclick` attribute you've defined.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> Every execution context has an associated VariableEnvironment.
>   Variables and functions declared in  ECMAScript code evaluated in an
>   execution context are added as bindings in that VariableEnvironment‘s 
>   Environment Record. For function code, parameters are also added as
>   bindings to that Environment Record.

See http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5 for the full documentation.

So yes it is equivalent to binding `var i = "hello";` since they will correspond to the same entry in the VariableEnviroment for the execution context.

You can see this in action by doing:

```
function hello(i) {
  var i ="no hello"; 
  console.log(arguments[0]);
}

hello("hi")

>>"no hello"
```

Comment: FWIW, ECMA has an online, linkable HTML version now: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5

Answer (score 0):

With your code:

```
<button onclick="myFunction('Hello')">Click Here!</button>

function myFunction(i) {
    alert(i); // display the i value on this case «Hello» 
}
```

«i» is a parameter / argument for your function

Now if you change hello by bye the i value will be «bye» only on your function

```
<button onclick="myFunction('Bye')">Click Here!</button>

function myFunction(i) {
    alert(i); // display «Bye» 
}
alert(i); // outside the function i is undefined ;)
```